# Why am I getting a TypeError when looping?

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python extension module, and one of my little test scripts is doing something strange, viz.:

```
x_max, y_max, z_max = m.size

for x in xrange(x_max):
    for y in xrange(y_max):
        for z in xrange(z_max):
            #do my stuff
```

What makes no sense is that the loop gets to the end of the first 'z' iteration, then throws a TypeError, stating that "an integer is required".  If I put a try...except TypeError around it and check the types of x, y, and z, they all come back as < type 'int' >.

Am I missing something here?

EDIT:  It appears I've got a problem somewhere in my extension code.  Pulling out those lines one by one revealed the culprit.  I suspect a reference counting error.  Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Does `# do my stuff` reassign `z_max`?  Though you don't properly show us the traceback, it seems the problem is with one of the `_max` variables -- not the three single-letter ones you've checked!-)

Comment: why don't you use `range()` is the list too long?

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by 'extension code'?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `x_max, y_max, z_max = m.size`

This syntax `x_max, y_max, z_max` expects a tuple/list on the other end of the equality sign so unless `m.size` is one -- and I take it it's an integer -- you need the following:

`x_max = y_max = z_max = m.size`

Comment: If `m.size` wasn't a sequence type, he would have gotten a `TypeError` before starting the loop.

Comment: Ah, yes. I guess I missed that part.